# Docker Postgresql Django Error - django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have been trying to deploy a docker django postgresql application.

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```
...
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    restart: always
    container_name: web
    command: gunicorn django_app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/static
      - media_volume:/media
    expose:
      - 80
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13.4-alpine
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.db
...
```

**.env.db**

```
POSTGRES_USER=user1
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password1
POSTGRES_DB=prod_db
```

**.env.prod**

```
...
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=prod_db
SQL_USER=user1
SQL_PASSWORD=password1
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
DATABASE=postgres
...
```

**settings.py**

```
...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": os.environ.get("SQL_ENGINE", "django.db.backends.sqlite3"),
        "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")),
        "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER", "user"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD", "password"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST", "localhost"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT", "5432")       
    }
}
...
```

**Full error message**

```
web      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
web      |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web      | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

**Resolution attempts:**

- testing with different postgresql image versions (update: and non-alpine version).
- setting POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD to password and trust without success.
- changing password and username many times
- changing db name
- adding 'restart: always' to 'web' in docker-compose

Do you have any idea whats required to resolve this error? If you require further details on my docker codebase to resolve this please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting this message during the build phase, or the execution phase?  (Do you try to `RUN ./manage.py migrate` in a Dockerfile?)  Or, is the `db` container exiting for some reason before the application starts?

Comment: @DavidMaze the lines in the error message are preceded by `web      ` so its probably when he's starting the compose stack

Comment: @jokulamoko can you try using a non `alpine` versioned PostgreSQL image? The Alpine distro has DNS resolution issues from time to time

Comment: @DavidMaze error arises in execution phase, no issues with the build phase. I do not run manage.py migrate in the Dockerfile, I run it post-execution but the same OperationalError is returned.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli I have started again with a non-alpine version of PostgreSQL image, unfortunately no luck same error.

Comment: Do you have any network settings for docker or the compose file that are not listed in the question?

Comment: No network settings, do you think network settings would help resolve the problem?